# HTML5 Audio object will not pause

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I've cooked up a simple musical keyboard using JS and HTML5, and now I want to force the previous note to pause when a new note is played.

```
var keyProto = {
    // other attributes and methods
    play: function() {
        var sound = new Audio("wav/" + timbre + this.name + this.octave + ".wav");
        if(!prevSound.paused && !prevSound.ended) {
            prevSound.pause();
        }   
        sound.play();
        prevSound = sound;
    }
};
```

However, the previous sound persists.

EDIT: Here's a "subset" of the entire program that features the same problem.

```
var soundFileNames = ["wav/sineA3.wav", "wav/sineB3.wav"];
var prevSound = new Audio(soundFileNames[0]);
var keys = [];

var keyProto = {
  soundFileName: "-",
  x: 0,
  y: 0,
  w: 0,
  h: 0,

  setDimensions: function(x, y, w, h) {
    this.x = x; 
    this.y = y;
    this.w = w;
    this.h = h;
  },

  draw: function(ctx) {
    ctx.strokeStyle = "#000000";
    ctx.strokeRect(this.x, this.y, this.w, this.h);
  },

  within: function(mx, my) {
    return this.x < mx && this.x+this.w > mx && this.y < my && this.y+this.h > my;
  },

  play: function() {
    var sound = new Audio(this.soundFileName);
    prevSound.pause();
    sound.play(); 
    prevSound = sound; 
  }
};

// Redraw canvas if window is resized 
var resize = function() {
  var cnvs = document.getElementById("cnvs");
  cnvs.height = window.innerHeight;
  cnvs.width = window.innerWidth;
  var c2 = cnvs.getContext('2d');
  c2.clearRect(0, 0, cnvs.width, cnvs.height);

  var midY = cnvs.height / 2;
  var margin = cnvs.width / 4;
  var keyWidth = (cnvs.width - 2*margin) / keys.length;
  var keyHeight = midY / 2;

  for(var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    keys[i].setDimensions(margin + i*keyWidth, midY-keyHeight/2, keyWidth, keyHeight);
    keys[i].draw(c2);
  }
}

// mouse pressed
var handleMouseDown = function(event) {
  var cnvsRect = document.getElementById("cnvs").getBoundingClientRect();
  mouseX = event.clientX - cnvsRect.left;
  mouseY = event.clientY - cnvsRect.top;
  for(var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++)
    if(keys[i].within(mouseX, mouseY))
      keys[i].play();
}

// "main"
for(var i = 0; i < soundFileNames.length; i++) {
  var newKey = Object.create(keyProto);
  newKey.soundFileName = soundFileNames[i];
  keys.push(newKey); 
}

resize();
```

And for good measure, the HTML

```
 <html>
   <head>
     <title>Fun Key</title>
   </head>
   <body onmousedown="handleMouseDown(event)" 
         onresize="resize()"   
         style="margin : 0px">
     <canvas id="cnvs"</canvas>
     <script src="funKeyMin.js"></script>
   </body>
 </html>
```

`prevSound` is a global variable, declared as `var prevSound = new Audio("wav/sineA3.wav");`. A bit of inspection using `console.log()` tells me that:

- `prevSound` looks like what I expect it to be: an object like `<audio preload="auto" src="wav/sineD3.wav">`, where the filename consistently matches that of the last sound played.
- `prevSound` already thinks it is paused (`prevSound.paused` is `true`) when the `if` is encountered, whether the previous note is still playing or not.

Removing the `if` clause and just leaving `prevSound.pause()` does not change the behavior. I can call `prevSound.pause()` at the end of the `draw()` routine (after the assignment `prevSound = sound`) and the new sound pauses immediately.

The key objects that make use of this method are created from `keyProto` using `Object.create(keyProto)`.  I recently read that prototypal inheritance is preferred over the use of constructors, and this is my first time using it.  However, my guess is that the problem stems from some nuance of global variables.

Comment: can you do `prevSound.volume=0` instead of pause()ing?

Comment: Could you show the rest of the code, or even better make a minimal snippet that demonstrates the issue? Are you sure you don't define an other variable named `prevSound` in the scope of the `keyProto` object? As it is right now, all I can say is "can't repro" : https://jsfiddle.net/foh6jqr9/

Comment: @dandavis the same thing happened. It's strange, prevSound appears to be the correct object when I use `console.log(prevSound)`, but doesn't act like it.